# For a Brownian motion $(B_t)_{t \geq 0}$, do we have $E[(B_\tau - B_\sigma)^2]=E[B_\tau^2 - B_\sigma^2]$ for stopping times $\sigma \leq \tau$?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, stopping-times, expected-value

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},(\mathcal{F}_t)_{t \geq 0}, P)$ be a filtered probability space and let $(B_t)_{t \geq 0}$ be a Brownian motion on that space. The question is if the following is true:

> For two bounded stopping times $\sigma \leq \tau$, we have
>   $$E[(B_\tau-B_\sigma)^2] = E[B_\tau^2 - B_\sigma^2]$$

If this is true, how can I see that it holds?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: It would be reasonable to assume that $\mathbb{E}(\tau)<\infty$; otherwise it's not even clear that the expectations are finite.

Comment: Do you have any hypothesis on $\sigma$ and $\tau$ (boundedness...)? Otherwise, you can just take $\sigma = T_1$ and $\tau = T_2$, where $T_a$ is the first hitting time of $a$.

Comment: @D.Thomine ,Yes I forgot to put it here. I assume boundedness of the stopping times

Comment: Here's an example to show that some sort of "smallness" hypothesis is needed for (at least) $\tau$: Suppose $\sigma$ is a finite (even bounded) stopping time with $\Bbb E[B_\sigma^2]>0$ and take $\tau:=\inf\{t>\sigma: B_t=0\}$. Then $\Bbb P[\tau<\infty, B_\tau=0]=1$. The left side of the equality you request is $\Bbb E[B_\sigma^2]$ while the right is $-\Bbb E[B_\sigma^2]$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a Brownian motion $(B_t)_{t \geq 0}$ it is well-known that $B_{\tau} \in L^2(\mathbb{P})$ for any bounded stopping time $\tau$, this follows e.g. from Wald's equation and ensures that all the expectations which appear in the remaining part of the answer are finite.

Recall the optional stopping theorem for martingales with continuous sample paths:

> Let $(M_t,\mathcal{F}_t)_{t \geq 0}$ be a martingale with continuous sample paths. If $\sigma,\tau$ are bounded stopping times such that $\sigma \leq \tau$ then $$\mathbb{E}(M_{\tau} \mid \mathcal{F}_{\sigma}) = M_{\sigma}$$ (in particular, $M_{\tau} \in L^1(\mathbb{P})$).

The Brownian motion is a martingale with continuous sample paths, and therefore we may apply the above result to obtain $$\mathbb{E}(B_{\tau} \mid \mathcal{F}_{\sigma}) = B_{\sigma}$$ for any two bounded stopping times $\sigma \leq \tau$. Combining this with the fact that $B_{\sigma}$ is $\mathcal{F}_{\sigma}$-measurable, we find that

$$\begin{align*} \mathbb{E}(B_{\sigma} B_{\tau}) &= \mathbb{E} \big[ \mathbb{E}(B_{\sigma} B_{\tau} \mid \mathcal{F}_{\sigma}) \big] \\ &= \mathbb{E} \big[B_{\sigma} \mathbb{E} (B_{\tau} \mid \mathcal{F}_{\sigma}) \big] \\ &= \mathbb{E}(B_{\sigma}^2). \end{align*}$$

Hence,

$$\mathbb{E}((B_{\tau}-B_{\sigma})^2) = \mathbb{E}(B_{\tau}^2)-2 \mathbb{E}(B_{\tau} B_{\sigma}) + \mathbb{E}(B_{\sigma}^2) = \mathbb{E}(B_{\tau}^2)-\mathbb{E}(B_{\sigma}^2).$$